# Having problem in generating elicit slot response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I want to create a dialogHook for a certain slot rather better to say a validation type of thing .If the slot returns true then only I will fire my elicit slot otherwise it would go as usual.Please help what would be my approach.I am relatively new to lex.

I have tried to to make a dialoghook on childExists but it is not working.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    os.environ['TZ']='America/New_York'
    time.tzset();
    logger.debug('event.bot.name={}'.format(event['bot']['name']))
    return dispatch(event);

def dispatch(intent_request):
    intent_name=intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    if intent_name=='HotelReservation':
        return book_hotel(intent_request)

def book_hotel(intent_request):
    slots=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    welcome=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['welcome']
    location=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['Location']
    fromDate=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['FromDate']
    adultCount=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['adultCount']
    nights=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['nights']
    childExists=intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['childExists']
    source=intent_request['invocationSource']
    session_attributes={}
    if source=='DialogCodeHook'and childExists.lower()=='yes':
        session_attributes={}
        return elicit_slot (
        session_attributes,
            'HotelReservation',
            'childCount',
             'AMAZON.NUMBER',            
            {
            'contentType':'PlainText',
            'content':'Please enter number of Children'
            }
        )
    elif source=='DialogCodeHook':
        output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])
    else:

        return close (
            session_attributes,
                'Fulfilled',{
                'contentType':'PlainText',
                'content':'Here is the temparature in'
                }
            )


#for fullfillment function
def close(session_attributes,fulfillment_state,message):
    response={
        'sessionAttributes':session_attributes,
        'dialogAction':{
            'type':'Close',
            'fulfillmentState':fulfillment_state,
            'message':message
        }
    }
    return response
#for elicit slot return
def elicit_slot(session_attributes, intent_name,slots,slot_to_elicit,message):
                        response= {
                         'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
                         'dialogAction': {
                         'type': 'ElicitSlot',
                         'intentName': intent_name,
                         'slots': slots,
                         'slotToElicit': slot_to_elicit,
                         'message': message
                         }
                       }
    return response;
def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }
```

Actually my slots should run as usual but after childExists slot I want to send a response of elicit
[This is the image of the slots available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc4Ko.png)

Comment: Double check your call of the `elicit_slot` function because your arguments don't match up. You do need to pass `slots` and don't need `'AMAZON.NUMBER'` there. Also you are trying to elicit slot `childCount` in the intent `HotelReservation`, but your image shows you don't have that slot in that intent.

Comment: But how can I get normal flow of slots and the lambda gets initiated only when childExist comes and thanks for helping

Comment: return elicit_slot (
        session_attributes,
            'HotelReservation',
            slots,'childCount',
            {
                 'contentType':'PlainText',
                 'content':'Please enter number of Children'
            }
        )

Comment: still i am getting error response

Comment: Yes, that's better, but it probably errors because you didn't create `childCount` as a slot yet. BTW, your Lambda is initialized with every user input, and you are getting a "normal flow" thanks to your Lambda returning `delegate`, which will elicit the next required slot. And that's why @sid8491's answer tells you to create the slot and do not mark it as required. His answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are asking the user `Do you have any children` and storing the response in `childExists` slot, if the answer is **yes** then you want to ask number of children.

So according to me, you need to have an extra slot `childCount` to store number of children. As this slot is not always required, **do not mark this required** in amazon lex console.

Now, you will check this in your `DialogCodeHook`, and ask the user accordingly only when `childExists == 'yes'`and there is no value in `childCount`. We are using combination of these condition is to ensure it does not run indefinitely.

```
def book_hotel(intent_request):
    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    welcome = slots['welcome']
    location = slots['Location']
    fromDate = slots['FromDate']
    adultCount = slots['adultCount']
    nights = slots['nights']
    childExists = slots['childExists']
    childCount = slots['childCount']
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
        if childExists.lower() == 'yes':
            if not childCount:
                return elicit_slot (
                    output_session_attributes,
                    'HotelReservation',
                    slots,
                    'childCount',            
                        {
                            'contentType':'PlainText',
                            'content':'Please enter number of Children'
                        }
                    )
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])

    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        return close (
            output_session_attributes,
                'Fulfilled',{
                'contentType':'PlainText',
                'content':'Here is the temparature in'
                }
            )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I have created childCount slot in my lex console but still I am getting this error:An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled       I also have a response card associated with welcome slot where the user is asked to give slot-types like do you want to book a hotel ----yes  or no in button options with slot_types

Comment: I have even unchecked the welcome slot as well along with childCount still I am getting this error

Comment: @GourabKonar there could be number of errors which could occur, it would be very hard to tell. better to put logger in your code and watch them in cloudwatch

Comment: @GourabKonar you have check marked & put your lambda function in `initialization and validation`? your lamda function will be called after all the slots are filled which are marked required, so it is not problem with your welcome slot i guess

Comment: Yes I have checked for intialization  and validation

Comment: There was a problem in importing the lower() function ,now I am getting response in lex ,Thanks for helping......but the problem now is FulfillmentCodeHook is not at all working ,Even I am not getting logs inside the if condition

Comment: Also I have a Confirmation Prompt at the end before fulfillment

Comment: @GourabKonar i would recommend to post a new question for your new issue with all relevant code and logs. that would be easy to solve.

Comment: Hi currently I am having problem with sending a response cards .I am getting this error:-